# Undervolting in Linux

Tags: linux, power-management, x86

Could you recommend me something different like Linux-PHC for undervolting in Linux?

I would like to undervolt my AMD Phenom 9850 CPU. I am using Debian squeeze x64.

For underclocking I use cpufrequtils, it is great CLI utility for lowering power consumption when you don't need power and want to insure yourself, that computer won't take more than XYWatts.

Is there anything better?

I prefer more CLI utility.

Comment: what is cpufrequtils lacking?

Comment: Actually it has been shown experimentally that on modern cpus, it does not save power to limit the frequency.  It is at least as good, if not better to finish work faster at the higher frequency, then get back into the deep sleep states, rather than spend more time working at the lower frequency.  The exception to this is if you are running crappy software that wastes cpu cycles in an infinite loop.

Comment: Guys, I actually want something, where I could lower voltages of my CPU. CPuFREQ allows it only in allowed size, but it is not possible to lower it for example under 1.1V on my phenom, which is voltage for lowest clock. And I want it UNDERVOLT under 1.1V. ON Windows is it possible. Under linux it was not working for me.